# Can a single electron slide down a smooth glass incline plane?

Tags: gravity, electrons, free-fall

It is said that there are detectors that can detect the impact of a single charged particle in transmission electron microscopy (TEM) that do not rely in the conversion of electrons into photons. In this manner, a single electron seem to act as a solid particle.

Assume we have a smooth glass incline plane in a vacuum shielded from all electrical fields. Electrons are emitted one at a time from a weak beta-decay source. Let's assume one such electrons falls on the glass inclined plane. Can this electron slide down the plane under its own weight.

Comment: Note the electron is smaller than the atoms in the glass!

Comment: The TEM imaging sensors I know of turn an energetic electron into lots of lower energy electron-hole pairs in a semiconductor junction. Just like photons get turned into electron-hole pairs in a semiconductor junction in your cell phone camera.

Comment: 2 glass surfaces are kept apart basically due to orbital electron repulsion. So electrons smaller than glass atoms may not be a factor.

Comment: @JonCuster, I bet your image sensors don't turn _electrons_ into electron-hole pairs. Maybe they use the _kinetic energy_ of the electron to create electron-hole pairs, but I'm guessing that the original electron survives the process. (completely unlike the fate of a photon that interacts with the sensor in a cell-phone camera.)

Comment: @SolomonSlow - yes, the original electron is not destroyed, but it does generate the e-h pairs so a signal actually gets generated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can understand why someone might ponder this. The key is to recognize that sliding is a classical phenomenon of macroscopic objects, and electrons belong to a completely different regime. **So no, an electron cannot “slide” down a glass plane.**

Glass is made of atoms held in a (more-or-less) rigid structure. These atoms have positively charged nuclei and negatively charged electron orbitals surrounding them. At the atomic scale, the electric potentials in a solid-state medium are enormously complex, especially for an amorphous material. Moreover, surfaces have the added complexity of dangling bonds and further defects.

If an electron is magically placed with no velocity in “contact” with an inclined glass plane, it will experience the complex electrical environment of the surface in addition to gravity. But also, it will itself distort the orbitals with which it interacts. Overall, the gravitational potential will be totally insignificant compared to the electrical potentials.

The only way one I could imagine anything remotely resembling sliding would be a for a completely contrived and unphysical situation, where the electrical forces just perfectly balance out such that the minuscule gravitational force would play a role. And furthermore, it wouldn’t be “sliding” but more like “hopping” from one lattice position to the next.

Comment: Say it's hopping and not sliding. Can a single electron be caught and falls through a glass funnel and downward and to be detected. It is said we have electron multiplier detectors. Wave- particle duality still mean an electron is also a physical particle.

Comment: @itsme as I said, no. The electric landscape of the glass surface just totally overpowers gravity. The way to do it is with magnetic lenses in ultra high vacuum, as in electron microscopes. Keep the electron away from atoms, and you can move it where you want. Add atoms, and all bets are off.